# Remove time from setFullYear and getFullYear

Tags: javascript, date

This one outputs 2021-04-04, 1:40 p.m.
How can I retain only the date, 2021-04-04.

```
console.log(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toLocaleString('en-CA'));
```

Comment: consider [edit] to specify language tag (possibly javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter option

```js
const curDateString = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10);
```

Adding a year

```js
const date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);

// and then
console.log( date.toISOString().substr(0,10) );
```

**Notes**

- `toISOString` returns UTC values, not local so within the local offset of midnight will return either yesterday's date where the user is east of Greenwich, or tomorrow's date for users west of Greenwich.
- Adding 1 year to 29 Feb will return 1 Mar,

Comment: Thank you. How do we get 2021-04-04. 1 year in the future.

Comment: Updated the answer to add a year

Comment: *toISOString* returns UTC values, not local so within the local offset of midnight will return either yesterday's date where the user is east of Greenwich, or tomorrow's date for users west of Greenwich. Also, adding 1 year to 29 Feb will return 1 Mar, which may or may not be expected but should be explained.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the clarification. Added your comment as notes

Comment: @Marin Buezas. Thanks. I just realized this today. On my PC date it is 4/6/2020. And the code above gives me 4/5/2021. How do we make it so that it displays 4/6/2021?

Comment: That would be by building the string from the getters which are local time (as in @Pakpoom... answer).

Comment: It's worth adding the following (and @RobG can correct me if I'm wrong) - If you are saving the date to a database elsewhere you should send it as UTC. That way other clients around the world would parse it to their local times. This will make sense depending on what your project requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const timeString = `${currentDate.getFullYear()+1}-${(currentDate.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2,'0')}-${currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
console.log(timeString);
```

Comment: O wait. Sorry. It does not display 2021-04-04. It displays 2020-04-04.

Comment: Also, note that `Date.getMonth()` return month that starts from `0` where January is `0`, February is `1` and so on. That's why for the month I have to plus `1`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How do we get 2021. I'm trying to get 1 year in the future.